Scala compile fails because of whitespace on a negative literal assignment?
This code fails to compile with scala 2.13:
case class Foo(bar: String, baz: Int = -1)
val foo = Foo("foo", baz=-2)

Says Not found value baz. This looks weird, doesn't it? Somehow, I have never encountered it before. Just wondering if someone knows of a reason why this should not be working? Or is it just a compiler bug, as basic as it looks?
Works fine if you add whitespace around (or even just after) the = ... or if you use anything that's not a negative literal constant instead of -2

I guess it sees =- as an "operator".

Hm, yeah I guess ... Looks like it. Does the same thing with String too, if you add a custom unary_-: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/CEGZKYyuQWeeHW29AWPefg

Since scala supports custom operators with symbols like = and -, the compiler can't make a distinction between the following possible choices:

baz =- 2 --> baz.=-(2)
baz = -2 --> baz.=(-2)

Spaces can be used to make this unambiguous.

Well, it's not really ambiguous in this context, since baz is a name of a function parameter (and there is no baz symbol in scope, let alone, one having a .=- defined) ... There is only one way to interpret it.

@Dima, that is correct. But that is usually not how languages are compiled. One of the very first steps in the compiler is the tokenizer. The tokenizer has no overview of what definitions are available. This is for good reasons, for example it allows for definitions to be in any order.

Yeah, makes sense I guess ...
